# configuration for hazelcast server from client

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm trying to define dynamic eviction configuration to Hazelcast but I want it to be on a different server and not create a new Hazelcast instance.

Is there any way to do this from the client or do I have to define it on an additional server that holds the Hazelcast?

Comment: Do you want to a) change an existing map's config on the fly or b) dynamically add a new map config on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

A client can not stay connected with two Hazelcast clusters, unless you do class unloading and loading sorcery on your own. So if by different server you meant a different cluster then you will have to disconnect the client from the other cluster before connecting to this one.

And if you meant a different server in the same cluster then thats not a correct analogy as all servers share data and configuration loaded by the clients. So even if you spin up a new server in existing cluster, its still part of that cluster. So when you load any config from that a client, that will be sent to all the other servers in the cluster.